# Compare a String-Value to a MySQLi Database-Value (VarChar/BigInt..)

Tags: java, php, mysqli

I need to receive all entries from a MySQLi database with a certain value (in my case: The Facebook-ID).

First im sending the value which im searching for in the database (fb_id):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id", fb_id));
  JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_your_events, "GET", params);
```

Receiving it in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['fb_id'])) {

$fb_id = $_GET['fb_id'];
```

Then having the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM UserEvents WHERE fb_id == $fb_id");
```

I already used different types for the fb_id column. BigInt (the ID would not fit in normal int) and VarChar do not work - i'm not getting any results. 
How do i get the query to work properly?

I'm grateful for any advice!

EDIT:

I also tried different comparisons in the query: = / == / === but none worked.

Comment: Have you tried: $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM UserEvents WHERE fb_id =$fb_id"); ?

Comment: your query is wrong, in mysql you use a single = to compare

Comment: Tried that before - no results